# Need to set default prop in react navigation

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

### **What I am trying to do**

I am using tabNavigator in react native to create an app where users can scroll through posts. I am trying to add a second tab for comments on posts, so a user can press on a post, and be directed to the second tab where they can see the comments.

### **My problem**

I have some code set up so that when the user presses a button on a post on the first tab, I navigate them to the second tab, and pass over the key of that post to the second tab:

```
onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('CommentScreen',{postKey: item.key}) }}
```

Then on my second tab, the app gets this info and displays it in a text component:

receiving data:

```
render() {
const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;
  return (
```

than later rendering it:

```
<Text>
  {params.postKey}
</Text>
```

All of this works as intended, except for I get an error when I first open the app. If I close the error and then use the app as intented, the key will show up. The error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'params.postKey')
```

I know I need to set the default to something, but I don't know how to. I would love some help giving this a default definition.

Comment: initialValues = { name: 'value'} and pass as props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because params hasn't yet been defined. So, you can make the error go away by simply changing

```
<Text>
  {params.postKey}
</Text>
```

to

```
<Text>
  {params && params.postKey}
</Text>
```

This basically says, "if `params` is defined, then output `params.postKey`".

But honestly it sounds like you're using the wrong UX component for this. Mobile app tabs are typically used for different, independent categories and are not usually dependent on one another. If I'm understanding you correctly, then the correct tool for the job would be a [`StackNavigator`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack). This is typically used when you're presenting a list of items (posts in your case), then want to navigate to more details about that list item (comments in your case). You can nest the StackNavigator inside the "Posts" tab.

Comment: I looked into StackNavigator, but I'm using CRNA, so I can only use tab navigator and drawer navigator. I might eject soon, but for now I'm just using tab navigator.

Comment: you don't need to eject to use StackNavigator https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/routing-and-navigation.html